# draw a chart on android

Tags: android, database, charts

I have stored in two near column in a DB in android these:

1-st column I have stored speed of a car
2-th column I have stored the moment of time when that car had tha speed

What I wanna do is to plot a graph which  has on the x-axis the period of time
and on the y-axis the speed of the car at that moment.

Has anyone any idea of how could I do that?

Comment: Try this link you may find it usefull


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264943/generating-graph-by-using-remote-data-from-database-on-achartengine


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814917/how-to-take-the-values-from-a-database-to-plot-a-bar-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can use android chart library as well u can paint a chart using canvas class.

these are library.

http://www.achartengine.org/

http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/

http://www.artfulbits.com/products/android/aiCharts.aspx

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Comment: open source; customizable via your XML layout; easy to use; have a few bug fixes of AChartEngine

Comment: let me know if you have any problem or question about it

Comment: @melanke has been warned and had their answers deleted for linking to their own project without disclosing that fact.