# Generating graph by using remote data from database on achartengine

Tags: java, android, graph, achartengine

I am trying to generate a graph using achartengine which pulls the data from a database and populates the graph using the data.
Following is the code that populates the graph. All tha data is stored in

"dataArraylist".
This code populates the data into graph

```
        CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Bar Graph");     //"series" = graph
        for(int i=0; i< size; i++)
        {
            series.add("Bar"+(i+1), dataArraylist.get(i));                      //add each of the value to the series i.e graph
        }


        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset= new XYMultipleSeriesDataset(); 
        dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());                                       //add the graph into a dataset


        // customisation for the first line
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);
        renderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); //create a new renderer.
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer); //renderer lets one to change the proerties of the graph i.e line colour etc
        mRenderer.setXTitle("X VALUES");
        mRenderer.setXTitle("Y VALUES");

        mRenderer.setChartTitle("This is title");

        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer,Type.DEFAULT, "Title"); //package the whole chart together


        return intent;
```

however when i try to compile it I get Null Exception error, following is the error that is received after null exception:

```
                       04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

I am also having problems on passing on the data from one activity to the graph activity. An answer would be appreciated

Full log is:

```
                   04-07 21:09:31.674: D/AndroidRuntime(4091): Shutting down VM
04-07 21:09:31.674: W/dalvikvm(4091): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     ... 11 more
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at hudds.fc.coach.ReadinessGraph.getIntent(ReadinessGraph.java:45)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at hudds.fc.coach.Overview.generateGraph(Overview.java:101)
04-07 21:09:31.713: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     ... 14 more
04-07 21:09:34.746: I/Process(4091): Sending signal. PID: 4091 SIG: 9
```

Following code downloads the data from database:

```
        try {
        if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

            String getsize=json.getString("size");
            size = Integer.parseInt(getsize);

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
            String getRating=json.getJSONArray("number").getJSONObject(i).getString("rating_number");
            int rating = Integer.parseInt(getRating);


            readinessRatng.add(rating);
            String printratings=readinessRatng.toString();
            Log.e("ratings are", printratings);
            }

        }


    else{

                     }
        }

    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: can you post your complete log

Comment: yes i want complete error log

Comment: Full log has been edited now :)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at  hudds.fc.coach.ReadinessGraph.getIntent(ReadinessGraph.java:45) check it once. line number 45 in ReadinessGraph

Comment: Yes that is the code that downloads the data from the database and feeds it to arraylist. It has been shown above, I tried downloading the data in another activity and tried printing it out, It works fine there.

Comment: might be but you data is not getting properly download

Comment: It is downloading on another activity. Can you recommend me any other good library for android graphs because I am having loads of difficulties with this one

Comment: this is the best and me too using the same. also once try with static data to ensure you have downloading problem

Comment: thank you, i will try it and will let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this [LINK](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) for achartengine

```
 public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getBarDemoRenderer() {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});
    SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    return renderer;
  }

 private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getBarDemoDataset() {
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    final int nr = 10;
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < SERIES_NR; i++) {
      CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Demo series " + (i + 1));
      for (int k = 0; k < nr; k++) {
        series.add(100 + r.nextInt() % 100);
      }
      dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
    }
    return dataset;
  }



private void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer) {
    renderer.setChartTitle("Chart demo");
    renderer.setXTitle("x values");
    renderer.setYTitle("y values");
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(5);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(250);
  }
```

Add the above method and call the below lines from your oncreate method

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = getBarDemoRenderer();
setChartSettings(renderer);
Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, getBarDemoDataset(), renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hi you have mentioned that second lines of code should be implemented in oncreate(); but so i did but I am getting errors on "Intent",  getBarDemoDataset() and setChartSettings(renderer).

Comment: Intent error is gone but it is not recognising these two methods                getBarDemoDataset() and setChartSettings(renderer);

Comment: added two more method and have added achartengine jar file

Comment: No errors left but its crashing now, following is the most understandable error that i could find:04-07 22:25:42.636: E/AndroidRuntime(4176): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dataset and renderer should be not null and should have the same number of series

Comment: i know what error is this. have you change any thing in above method and what is the value of SERIES_NR in your code

Comment: depending on value of SERIES_NR you must change getBarDemoRenderer()

Comment: I did not know what SERIERS_NR is as it was not defined in the code so presuming it was to loop the data i changed it to 4, where do i define SERIES_NR

Comment: change it to two because in getBarDemoRenderer() i had added two SimpleSeriesRenderer

Comment: Yep another issue, It is showing error on graphicalactivity even tho i dont have any activity called graphicalActivity                   :     04-07 22:39:07.473: E/AndroidRuntime(4212): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hudds.fc.coach/hudds.fc.coach.Overview}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {hudds.fc.coach/org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: add <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" /> in your manifeast file it internally call this activity

Comment: Haha, Amaazing, Beautiful..Just what I wanted, Thank you for the help.. Just a quick question.. Do i have to use the given method on create or I just attach it to a button and trigger it with a button