# How to take the values from a database to plot a bar chart?

Tags: android, sqlite, bar-chart, achartengine

Hi i am new to android and i am developing an app to display the top 10 travel destinations using achartengine. The problem is that i am using random values generated to plot the graph. What i need is to connect a database created using sqlite data browser to plot the graph. I am following the following tutorial to draw the graph http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9fozQ5NlSo. But i am not finding many tutorials on how to connect a database to plot a bar chart. Please post any links for the above.

```
package flu.solutions.travelsense;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type;
import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.SimpleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.Orientation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.Menu;
public class ChartActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = getBarDemoRenderer();
        setChartSettings(renderer);
        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, getBarDemoDataset(), renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public Intent createIntent() 

     {

    String[] titles = new String[] { "Top 10 Destinations", " " };
    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values.add(new double[] { 8, 6, 4, 6, 7, 7, 9, 5, 7, 8, 8 });
    values.add(new double[] {});

    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.RED, Color.BLACK};

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

    setChartSettings(renderer);

    renderer.setXLabels(1);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);

    renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Bangalore");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Mysore");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Chennai");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(4, "Delhi");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(5, "Kolkatta");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(6, "Kashmir");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(7, "Hyderabad");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(8, "Mumbai");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(9, "Kerala");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(10, "Gujarat");

    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
      SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
      seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
      }

    return ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
    }

    public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getBarDemoRenderer() {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        return renderer;
      }

     private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getBarDemoDataset() {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        final int nr = 10;
        Random r = new Random();
        int SERIES_NR = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < SERIES_NR; i++) {
          CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Demo series " + (i + 1));
          for (int k = 0; k < nr; k++) {
            series.add(100 + r.nextInt() % 100);
          }
          dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
        }
        return dataset;
      }



    private void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer) {
        renderer.setChartTitle("Chart demo");
        renderer.setXTitle("x values");
        renderer.setYTitle("y values");
        renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(5);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(250);
      }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_chart, menu);
        return true;
    }
      }
```

Can you tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: you simply need to load the array of doubles that you'd use by looping through a database query. what have you tried so far?

Comment: No i don't know how to connect a database to my app. Completely new here.@mango

Comment: the answer to something like this is too verbose, and requires much info not provided, to be adequately handled here. with a here's a couple tutorials on the database: http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html and http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html. give them a shot and see if you can piece what you need together. then come back for more specific issues.

Comment: Thanks i'll try that and get back if i have any issues....:)

Answer (score 1):

First tell me where your database is 
1> is it is local to your application 
2> is it in server(there are various ways to access ex:you can send http request for getting datas from the server)
3>is the database is  in anther application in your phone you can use content provider to access data.

try this code

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context mycontext;

    //private String DB_PATH = mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "(datbasename).sqlite";//the extension may be .sqlite or .db
    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    /*private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                        + mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                        + "/databases/";*/

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
        this.mycontext=context;
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if (dbexist) {
            //System.out.println("Database exists");
            opendatabase(); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
            createdatabase();
        }
    }

    public void createdatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if(dbexist) {
            //System.out.println(" Database exists.");
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copydatabase();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }   

    private boolean checkdatabase() {
        //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
        boolean checkdb = false;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            checkdb = dbfile.exists();
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        }
        return checkdb;
    }

    private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/(packagename)/databases   /(datbasename).sqlite");

        // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0) {
            myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();
    }

    public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null) {
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

}
```

for reading the database from asset folder..

Comment: I have created a database using sqlite databrowser and copied the database into the assets folder.@Abhijit

Comment: String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
It is showing that outfilename is not used.@Abhijit